# How to hide a prerelease version from npm?

Tags: npm

At the moment, npmjs.com shows version 1.10.3 of `eslint`:

[image]

However, running `npm show eslint versions` reveals an alpha version:

```
[ '0.0.4',
  '0.0.5',
  ...
  '1.10.2',
  '1.10.3',
  '2.0.0-alpha-1' ]
```

What causes npm to hide the alpha version?

---

I published an alpha version of `react-autosuggest`, and was hoping that npm will hide it as well, but npm shows it:

[image]

Any ideas how could I hide an alpha version from npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag):

> Publishing a package sets the "latest" tag to the published version unless the --tag option is used. For example, npm publish --tag=beta.

I ended up publishing a new version, 2.2.4, which got by default the `latest` tag. This caused 2.2.4 to appear on npmjs.com. Now, if I publish a new alpha version using `--tag`:

```
npm publish --tag=3.0-latest
```

it won't be visible on npmjs.com.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjVS1U1cdXM) explains how distribution tags work.